# Why am I getting Run-time error 91 error in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to VBA and I am writing a code to copy-paste from one workbook to another. It looks something like this:

```
dim x as workbook
dim y as workbook

Set y=ThisWorkbook
z=workbook.open(path to file)
z.sheets("1").Range.("A1").Copy
y.sheets("1").Cells(1,1).PasteSpecial
z.close
```

When I run the code, workbook z opens, but then I get the following error:

> Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set.

What am I missing?

Comment: 2 things: `Set z=workbookS.open(path to file)`

Comment: You did not `Set` the 'z' workbook. Workbooks must be `Set`, the same way you did for `y`. I'm assuming you have `dim z as Workbook` somewhere, if not you should.

Comment: Strange that you use `Range("A1")` and `Cells(1, 1)` which refer to the same address. If your code is really working with those cells I would do a value transfer once your book is set properly. i.e. `y.Sheets("1").Range("A1").Value = z.Sheets("1").Range("A1").Value`

Comment: Thank you both.. It is working now.. I am curious what does the Set do exactly?

Comment: @urdearboy I was just experimenting if changing range to cells (or vice-versa) would fix the error

Comment: [SET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement)

Comment: @urdearboy Objects can still be variable type. _SET: Assigns an object reference to a variable or property._  I think you made a typo with unlike.